# How to install Elasticsearch on 16.04 LTs

Tags: 16.04, search, ruby

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on virtual box and I'd like to install `elasticsearch` in order to use it with [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#get-started). I've done a search on google on how to do the installation, but I have found mutiple guides that have a few differences which got me a little bit confused, for instance:

[Installing elasticsearch on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.accesstomemory.org/en/docs/2.3/admin-manual/installation/linux/ubuntu-xenial/#elasticsearch)

[Digital Ocean: Install and Configure Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04)

(see @ Prerequisites)

How should I install elasticsearch safely, without messing up my development environment?

Comment: If my solution worked for your problem, could you please accept the answer? In that way people know if the problem is solved. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I missed you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Elastic has their own guide to install elasticsearch with Debian packages. you can find it on their website.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

I used this one and now everything works like a charm.

Elasticsearch requires Java 8 or later:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
```

Install Elasticsearch

```
$ wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
$ echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-5.x.list
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

**some remarks (from elastic website):**

- Do not use `add-apt-repository` as it will add a deb-src entry as well, but we do not provide a source package. If you have added the deb-src entry, you will see an error like the following:

> ```
> Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file
> Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
> ```

=> Delete the deb-src entry from the /etc/apt/sources.list file and the installation should work as expected.

- If two entries exist for the same Elasticsearch repository, you will see an error like this during apt-get update:

> Duplicate sources.list entry
>   https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt/ ...`

=> Examine `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-5.x.list` for the duplicate entry or locate the duplicate entry amongst the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Answer (score 3):

For very basic installation of ElasticSearch **1.x or 2.x** on Ubuntu 16.04

(the same goes for Ubuntu 14.04) do the next few steps on fresh install Ubuntu:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`
6. `java -version`

**//For 2.x; elasticsearch 2.4.0**

1. `wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/deb/elasticsearch/2.4.0/elasticsearch-2.4.0.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-2.4.0.deb`
3. `service elasticsearch status`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y curl lynx links`
5. `lynx http : // localhost : 9200`

OR

5. `curl -X GET 'http : // localhost:9200'`

Answer (score 2):

## Installing ElasticSearch 6.8.6 on Ubuntu 16

The latest version at the time of writing was 7 but we needed version 6 for compatibility reasons so using the typical `apt-get` package manager wouldn't work. Instead we opted to install the package directly.

1. Download and install the debian package for version 6.8.6:

   ```
   wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.8.6.deb
   wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.8.6.deb.sha512
   shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-6.8.6.deb.sha512 
   sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-6.8.6.deb
   ```
2. Setup elasticsearch to start automatically on boot.

   ```
   sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
   ```
3. Start the elasticsearch service.

   ```
   bash
   sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
   ```
4. Confirm elasticsearch is running:

   ```
   $ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/?pretty"
   {
     "name" : "dfdnndd",
     "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
     "cluster_uuid" : "abcdadsf123234234",
     "version" : {
       "number" : "6.8.6",
       "build_flavor" : "default",
       "build_type" : "deb",
       "build_hash" : "3d9f765",
       "build_date" : "2019-12-13T17:11:52.013738Z",
       "build_snapshot" : false,
       "lucene_version" : "7.7.2",
       "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
       "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
     },
     "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
   }
   ```

   *NOTE: Sometimes it takes a few seconds to spin up.*
5. Configure as necessary:

   ```
   vi /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
   ```

   For example, uncomment this line, `#network.host: localhost`, and replace `localhost` with your server's IP address so it looks someting like this: `network.host: 123.123.123.123`.

Answer (score 0):

**Elasticsearch 7.x installation on Ubuntu 20.04**

- Installing openjdk 11 (8th version also have been used without issues):

  ```
    sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
  ```
- Elasticsearch installation

  ```
    curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
    echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install elasticsearch
  ```
- Configure elasticsearch configuration file `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

  ```
    cluster.name: myclaster
    node.name: mynode1
    network.host: 192.168.0.5
  ```

  Uncomment the above option and specify your IP address or just `localhost` if you do not desire to give access to it through your local network.
- If you desire to allow access to it from your local network, then specify only IP addresses of specific machine you want to grant access from:

  ```
    sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.55 to any port 9200
  ```

  Do not allow access from any host, because of it does not have restrictions.
- Start elasticsearch service:

  ```
    sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
  ```
- Test if your elasticsearch service is running using telnet from both machines (192.168.0.5 and 192.168.0.55):

  ```
    telnet 192.168.0.5 9200
  ```

  You'll get the next

  ```
    Trying 192.168.0.5...
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
  ```

  if elasticsearch service is not running

  You'll get the next if it is running but blocked by firewall:

  ```
    Trying 192.168.0.5...
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
  ```

  You'll get the next output if the service is running and it is allowed in firewall:

  ```
    Trying 192.168.0.5...
    Connected to 192.168.0.5.
    Escape character is '^]'.
  ```
- Test elasticsearch configuration by:

  ```
    curl -X GET 'http://192.168.0.5:9200'
  ```

More details [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-20-04)